# How to generate a random integer using math.random class

Tags: java, class, math, random, int

I am having trouble with the `RandInt()` method as it will not return a random integer. The result must be an int ranged `0-9` and must use the math.random class. This is my code below:

```
public class RandNumGenerator {
    public static int RandInt() {
        int n = (int) Math.random() * 10;
        return n;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually a question about operator precedence and has little to do with random numbers.

Comment: `rand.nextInt()` is better as other random generators also use `rand.nextInt()` or `rand.next()` internally

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc That information is of little use to OP who, quoting, `must use the math.random class`.

Comment: Also note that you are not doing anything with the returned value - not assigning it, not printing it, or anything.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, the real question is why the author must use the math.random.

Answer (score 5):

You should cast the double to int after multiplying by 10 :

```
int n = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
```

Otherwise you'll always get 0 (since `Math.random()<1.0` and therefore `(int)Math.random()` is always 0).

Answer (score 3):

[Casting has higher priority than `*`](http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php) so code

```
(int) Math.random() * 10;
```

is same as

```
((int) Math.random()) * 10;
```

and since `Math.random()` returns values in range `[0; 1)` (1 - excluded) casting to `int`

```
(int) Math.random()
```

will produce `0` which multiplied by 10 will also return `0`.

You may want to use

```
(int) (Math.random() * 10)
```

or easier to read and maintain `Random#nextInt(max)` to generate range `[0; max)` (`max`-exclusive)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put brackets around the multiplication

```
int n = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
```

what's happening is

```
int n = ((int) Math.random()) * 10;
```

as `Math.random()` is always greater or equal to 0 and less than 1, converting it to an integer will always equal zero. Multiplying it by 10 will do nothing.

Comment: @Pshemo nope, they're all there

Comment: @Pshemo ah, good point. I did miss that.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't really be using Math.random() to generate random integers, as it will generate random floats (i.e, decimal numbers)

You should do something similar to this

```
Random myRandom = new Random();
int randomInt = myRandom.nextInt(10);
```

Comment: OP: `must use the math.random class.`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Asking a method to return an integer when it's set to return a float is quite literally impossible. Unless you want to cast it, which is pointless when the Math.random uses the Random class anyway.

Comment: *using* a method in a calculation is different from *asking* it to return the end result. You appear to be alone in your interpretation of OP's goal.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik In what scenario would casting the return value of a method to what you want, be better than using a method that does the exact same thing without casting? The only reason I see for doing this, is in an educational environment, in which case the OP shouldn't be learning to do things inefficiently.

Comment: So ask OP to give you a contact to his educational institution, then complain about their curriculum. Meanwhile, OP will be expected to do what the assignment asks for.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Touche.